# vim user defined command: reopen current file for editing

Tags: vim, vimrc

I have a user defined command in vim that does a chmod on the current file. Once that's done, reopen the current file for editing (with the newly updated properties) by issuing:

```
:e[dit]!
```

I'd like for the command to do this automatically. How do I do this?

```
command! PerforceOpen echo system('chmod u+w '.shellescape(substitute(resolve(expand('%:p')), '-debug', '', 'g')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append the command to your custom command:

```
command! PerforceOpen echo system(...) | edit!
```